# Setting the value of integer programatically in xml file

Tags: android, xml, integer

I have this program that shows for example 3 `EditTexts`, it gets this value "3" from xml file named integers. What I want now is that user could change this value.

Here is the code I am using now:

```
int max = this.getResources().getInteger(R.integer.maxValue);
```

as I said it draws currently 3 `EditText` on screen, but I want user to be able to change this amount through settings.

here is my integers.xml

```
<resources>

    <integer name="maxValue">3</integer>

</resources>
```

So how do I change value in xml file?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you get the value directly from the user instead of the resources?

Answer (score 0):

If you want the user to input any number then make a variable to hold that number and ask the user to input a number.

Comment: so it is impossible to change the value once it is set in xml?

Comment: I don't know if is impossible or not but I have never done it this way.